# Show white header show when navigate page in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

When I navigate from one page to another in place of header show white header(Reload header) every time.

[image]

I remove `cache: false` from every piece of code, but still it shows.

Please help me. It's annoying.

Comment: The sliding is from the browser right? Try to set the body background color same as header

Comment: @Aziz I capture in my  phone running my Ionic app

Comment: @Aziz I set the body background color same as header but till now I get white screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply use below CSS code and my problem solved :)

```
ion-view{
 background-color: #2f354a !important; //use color which is used in header color
}
```